# What happened to byte and packet counters in conntrack?

Tags: linux, conntrack, nf-conntrack

[Netfilter's conntrack docs](http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/manual.html#conntrack) show an example output of `conntrack -L` that contains `bytes=` and `packets=` counters, but when I run it I only see IP and port information.

I'm aware that the docs are really out of date, and specifically mention `ip_conntrack`, which has since been replaced with `nf_conntrack`, but I'm hoping there's some way to enable the counters again.

Is there a way to get that information, or have these counters been removed?

I'm using ubuntu 14.04, with kernel 3.13

Comment: Try iptables -vnL

Comment: Will ifconfig give you the trackers you want?

Comment: The counters you guys mention are per interface, but I'm interested in counters per *connection*.

Answer (score 6):

Turns out I just needed to enable accounting by doing (as root):

```
/bin/echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_acct
```

After this, byte and packet counts appear in the conntrack output.

Comment: I wonder why they are not enable per default... memory contraints? performance impacts?